# Insert string into 'haystack' whenever 'needle' is found and put the haystack back together

Tags: php

```
<?php  

    $name = "Peter_Piper";

    // %name% is placeholder for $name

    $rhyme = "%name% picked a peck of pickled peppers.
              A peck of pickled peppers %name% picked.
              If %name% picked a peck of pickled peppers,
              Where's the peck of pickled peppers %name% picked?";

          strpos($rhyme,'%name%');   
          $split = explode("%name%", $rhyme);

          $rhyme  = $split[0];                                          
          $rhyme .= $name;
          $rhyme .= $split[1];
          $rhyme .= $name;
          $rhyme .= $split[2];
          $rhyme .= $name;
          $rhyme .= $split[3];
          $rhyme .= $name;
          $rhyme .= $split[4]; 


    echo $rhyme;

    ?>
```

The above example accurately portrays what I am trying to do.

However it only works because I knew how many times "Peter_Piper" occurs. Since I will not know how many times (if any) %name% will occur, it will require looping.

```
    <?php
$name = "Peter_Piper";

$rhyme = "%name% picked a peck of pickled peppers.
          A peck of pickled peppers %name% picked.
          If %name% picked a peck of pickled peppers,
          Where's the peck of pickled peppers %name% picked?";

      strpos($rhyme,'%name%');   
      $split = explode("%name%", $rhyme);

foreach ($split as $item) {
  echo "$item";
}


?>
```

Now I have the bulk of the rhyme but "Peter_Piper" is missing. I understand why "Peter_Piper" is missing. I just can't figure out how insert the name.

Comment: Why not simply use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: Because I didn't know about str_replace() or how easy it is to use. Thank you Mark Baker Grzesiek and shadyyx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use str_replace?

```
str_replace("%name%", $name, $rhyme);
```

Comment: Nothing much, but you forgot the "" around %name%. It should be str_replace("%name%", $name, $rhyme)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `preg_replace`.

```
preg_replace('/(%name%)/ug', $name, $rhyme);
```

Or change `%name%` occurences in the `$rhyme` for `%1$s` and you can then call

```
sprintf($rhyme, $name);
```

Commonly used one is as well

```
str_replace("%name%", $name, $rhyme);
```